# I am not able to design like this

Tags: android, android-layout

Please see the below link how design look alike

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? That's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the using BottomAppBar with fabAttached attribute 
and use FloatingActionButton with layout_anchor attribute relating BottomAppBar and set the of floatingactionbutton usign fabAlignmentMode attribute

here is a nice artical [link](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708)